# vsftp - GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-18.04, filezilla, vsftpd

I am running vsftp on Ubuntu 18.04 on Azure. Filezilla clients are 3.52.2 (Windows) and 3.28.0 (Ubuntu 18.04). The error seen at the client is the same for both.

```
Status: Resolving address of myserver.com
Status: Connecting to xxxxx...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Error:  GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Here is /etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
# with and without allow_writeable_chroot gives the same problem
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
anon_world_readable_only=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
passwd_chroot_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
ssl_enable=YES
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
ls_recurse_enable=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
ascii_upload_enable=NO
ascii_download_enable=NO
local_root=/var/www/ftp
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=60001
pasv_max_port=60002
port_enable=YES
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
pasv_address=myserver.com
file_open_mode=0666
local_umask=0022
# I would like not to need this, but cURL does not work without it
require_ssl_reuse=NO
```

The users have accounts created, in /etc/passwd, and they are the owners of the indicated directories:

```
user1:x:1002:1002::/var/www/ftp/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:1003:1003::/var/www/ftp/user2:/bin/bash
```

/var/log/vsftpd.log has the following:

```
Mon Feb  1 12:42:15 2021 [pid 8303] CONNECT: Client "109.252.44.21"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:15 2021 [pid 8303] FTP response: Client "109.252.44.21", "220 Welcome to services back end"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:15 2021 [pid 8303] FTP command: Client "109.252.44.21", "AUTH TLS"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:15 2021 [pid 8303] FTP response: Client "109.252.44.21", "234 Proceed with negotiation."
Mon Feb  1 12:42:17 2021 [pid 8303] FTP command: Client "109.252.44.21", "USER user1"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:17 2021 [pid 8303] [user1] FTP response: Client "109.252.44.21", "331 Please specify the password."
Mon Feb  1 12:42:17 2021 [pid 8303] [user1] FTP command: Client "109.252.44.21", "PASS <password>"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:17 2021 [pid 8302] [user1] OK LOGIN: Client "109.252.44.21"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:17 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP response: Client "109.252.44.21", "230 Login successful."
Mon Feb  1 12:42:17 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP command: Client "109.252.44.21", "PBSZ 0"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:17 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP response: Client "109.252.44.21", "200 PBSZ set to 0."
Mon Feb  1 12:42:18 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP command: Client "109.252.44.21", "PROT P"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:18 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP response: Client "109.252.44.21", "200 PROT now Private."
Mon Feb  1 12:42:18 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP command: Client "109.252.44.21", "PWD"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:18 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP response: Client "109.252.44.21", "257 "/" is the current directory"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:19 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP command: Client "109.252.44.21", "TYPE I"
Mon Feb  1 12:42:19 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP response: Client "109.252.44.21", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Mon Feb  1 12:42:19 2021 [pid 8304] [user1] FTP command: Client "109.252.44.21", "PASV"
```

Filezilla client is set to use explicit FTP over TLS if available, passive mode is forced.

On the server incoming ports 21 and 60000-60002 are open, as well as outgoing ports.

When I test with cURL:

```
curl -u user1:password -v --ssl -k ftp://myserver.com
```

I receive the directory listing without problems:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: ftp://myserver.com/
*   Trying xxxxxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myserver.com (xxxxx) port 21 (#0)
< 220 Welcome to services back end
> AUTH SSL
< 234 Proceed with negotiation.
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*  xxxxxxxxxxxx
*  start date: Mar 19 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 24 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=Thawte RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> USER user1
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 331 Please specify the password.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> PASS password
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 230 Login successful.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> PBSZ 0
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 200 PBSZ set to 0.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> PROT P
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 200 PROT now Private.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> PWD
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 257 "/" is the current directory
* Entry path is '/'
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||60001|)
*   Trying xxxxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connecting to xxxxx (xxxxx) port 60001
* Connected to myserver.com (xxxxx) port 21 (#0)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> TYPE A
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> LIST
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
* Maxdownload = -1
* Doing the SSL/TLS handshake on the data stream
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL re-using session ID
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Server certificate:
*  xxxxxxxxxxxxx
*  start date: Mar 19 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 24 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=Thawte RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
drwxrwxr-x    2 1003     33           4096 Jan 30 10:59 user1
drwxrwxr-x    2 1002     33           4096 Jan 30 10:59 user2
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Remembering we are in dir ""
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< 226 Directory send OK.
* Connection #0 to host myserver.com left intact
```

I have a similar problem to that with Filezilla with WinSCP.

Any ideas? I have seen a lot of posts about GnuTLS -15, but none of the solutions have made any change for me, and my forehead is getting sore from banging my head against the keyboard for several days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has been able to come up with anything. So this is how I solved it:

1. Turned off vsftpd. This is based on so many blog entries calling out problems with vsftpd with Filezilla, WinSCP, Cyberduck, and others.
2. Configured sftp as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes

The result is not as nice - the users do not have write access to their own directories, so I had to create a subdirectory "files" under each user for file load. But at least it works under every client that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have same prob as you get. It could be the `tls1.0` issue.
Try disable ssl_tlsv1:

In vsftp.conf:

```
ssl_tlsv1=NO
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
```